# Show only month & year jQuery Datepick Plugin

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Hello I've been using [Keith Wood's](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html?#layout) Datepick jQuery plugin. But what I want is only to show the month and year on the selection. I know that there is fix already here but it's for jQuery Datepicker.

Thanks :)

Comment: The Month and Year only? So you need two dropdown boxes as Keith uses and scrap the entire plugin for selecting the day?

Comment: No man just for one form. I've been dealing with a whole lot of dates the entire time but my requirement for that form is only month and year. I love the plugin don't get me wrong =)... Cheers :'(

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
 $('#birthdate').datepicker({
dateFormat: 'mm/yy',
changeMonth:true,
changeYear:true
});
```

Comment: I think your answer is for the jQUery Datepicker not datepick. I've already tried something similar to that code ang it doesn't work.

Comment: yes I answerd for datepicker , in datepick there is a option altFormat: 'MM - yyyy'

Comment: Oh fancy! Now this is what I call genius! Thanks man! You's the bomb!

Comment: Nah, it still displays the days but at least I know now that there is an altFormat option.

Comment: did you try this one dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm'

Comment: Thanks Poonama for helping me figure this one out. So for those who'll come across the similar problem here is the fix:

    $('.dateNew').datepick({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm', 
      altField: '.dateNew', 
      altFormat: 'mm-yy',
      yearRange: '1930:2011', 
      changeMonth:true,
      changeYear:true
     });

Answer (score 0):

This is for future reference. This one did it. Thanks for those who helped

```
$('.dateNew').datepick({ 
           dateFormat: 'yy-mm', 
           altField: '.dateNew', 
           altFormat: 'mm-yy', 
           yearRange: '1930:2011', 
           changeMonth:true, changeYear:true  
    });
```