# Year Not Showing In Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

I am trying to select the year, but year not showing in the calendar.

My code is written below:

```
$('#startdate').datepicker({
  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  orientation: "auto",
  autoclose: true
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show only month & year jQuery Datepick Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306877/show-only-month-year-jquery-datepick-plugin)

Comment: you mean not showing like this?
https://gyazo.com/ecead7237b9ed9e1ab241c8a79e07273
can you include the library you are using for picker because there are lot of datepicker

Comment: yes, this is my problem. I am using plugin called https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding these to your options.

```
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#startdate').datepicker({
  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  orientation: "auto",
  autoclose: true,
  changeYear:true
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.